# I can't use Scrapy on all web pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to using Scrapy and I need to extract the information of some of the prices of Walmart Canada. The problem is that it does not extract anything, but it only happens to me with Walmart Canada, since when using Scrapy on another web page, it works correctly.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class WalmartItem(Item):
    barcodes = Field()
    sku = Field()


class WalmartCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'walmartCrawler'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/apple-gala/6000195494284']


    def parse(self, response):
        item = ItemLoader(WalmartItem(), response)
        item.add_xpath(
            'barcodes', "//div[@class='css-1dar8at e1cuz6d10']/div[@class='css-w8lmum e1cuz6d11']/div[contains(text(), 'UPC')]/parent::node()/div[2]/text()")
        item.add_xpath(
            'sku', "//*[contains(text(), 'UPC')]/parent::node()/div[2]/text()")
        yield item.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath doesn't work,
one way to do it is using regex

```
import re,ast
sku = re.search(r'"sku":"(\d+)',response.text).groups()[0]
barcodes = ast.literal_eval(re.search(r'"upc":(\[.*?\])',response.text).groups()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: You **cannot** assume Scrapy will work to extract data from any web page.

Some websites load information using browser scripting (JavaScript code) or AJAX requests. These processes are executed in the browser after the initial response is received from the server. This means that when you receive the HTML response in Scrapy, you may not receive the information as you see it in the browser.

Instead, to check the response that you will receive in Scrapy, you should check on the **Network** tab inside the **DevTools** of your browser (In Google Chrome you can access them with `Right Click > Inspect`). Here, search for the initial request that the browser is doing to the server. Once you have found it, you can check which is the response to that request. This is the response you are going to receive in Scrapy.

[image: networks tab]

Therefore, inside Scrapy you can only work with this HTML. And as you can see, the price is not available. In this cases you must find another alternatives such as: a) Using [Selenium Web Driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html), b) Finding the data of the product inside an `script` tag on the HTML (which is the way to go in this case, check the first `script` tag inside the HTML). c) Do an extraction via API.

Take a look at this walmart.ca extraction script which goes for b) solution for each product in a list of products:
https://github.com/juansimon27/scrapy-walmart/blob/master/product_scraping/spiders/spider.py

On top of this, in this specific case of walmart.ca, if you do not use the correct **user agent** in your requests, walmart.ca may respond you with an: `<h2>Your web browser is not accepting cookies.</h2>` or something like: `Your browser is not able to execute JS`.

Configure the following user agent to avoid these problems:

```py
    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; http://www.google.com/bot.html) Chrome/W.X.Y.Z‡ Safari/537.36 '
    }
```

In your script you can put this `custom_settings` definition just below your `start_urls` variable, or instead use a `settings.py` file with the USER_AGENT config.